# when pressing enter, the text input value disappears (plain js)

Tags: javascript

so i was working on some sort of library to help me out with my future projects, and perhaps learn more things, however, i had a problem:

i have a class called "Terminal" which initializes a terminal view in the window, and i have made a method in it called "confirm" which will give the user a question answered with either "y" or "n", my problem is when the user inputs something else, i made it so it will retype the same confirm message with the same results, just like the real terminals, however, whenever i press enter (which is detected by an event listener) it will clear out the input value. i was originally using a form, but i had some other problems with it, so instead i went for a text input with an enter key listener, however, the problem still presents

```js
confirm({text = "INPUT TEXT HERE",time = 1000,callbackY = () => console.log("no callback on true is defined !"), callbackN = () => console.log("no callback on false is defined !")} = {}) {
        this.timer += time
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.panel.innerHTML += 
            `<div class="terminal__confirm">
                <p class="terminal__print">${text} (Y/N)</p>
                <input type="text" class="terminal__confirm-input">
            </div>
            `
            let confirmPanelTable = this.panel.querySelectorAll(".terminal__confirm")
            let confirmPanel = confirmPanelTable[this.confirmPanelCount]
            console.log(confirmPanel)   
            this.confirmPanelCount += 1
            let inputForm = confirmPanel.querySelector(".terminal__confirm-input")
            let submitValue = ""
            inputForm.focus()

            inputForm.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
                if(event.keyCode === 13) {
                    if(inputForm.value === "y" || inputForm.value === "Y") {
                        callbackY()
                    } else if(inputForm.value === "n" || inputForm.value === "N"){
                        callbackN()
                    } else {
                        this.confirm({text,time,callbackY,callbackN})
                    }
                }
            })
        },this.timer)
    }
```

(this is the full code: https://codepen.io/almajd3713/pen/MWaZraE )
I hope that someone would help me with fixing this, because i wasted so much time trying to do so

Comment: `this.panel.innerHTML += …` is where this messes up. You are _recreating_ all existing content of that element this way - and the existing innerHTML _read_ from the element, does not contain the entered value of the input field (because that never makes it into the DOM.)

Comment: what could i do in order to fix that?

Comment: You could use proper DOM methods to create and append new elements, instead of using innerHTML. You could also _read_ the values of all currently existing input fields first, then append the content via `.innerHTML += …`, and then loop over the (now “wiped”) fields to explicitly _set_ their value again.